# Ant: Need to set a new property in a target for later use

Tags: java, ant

Relevant portion of the ant script:

```
<target name="checkOS">
    <condition property="isWindows" value="true">
        <os family="windows" />
    </condition>

    <condition property="isUnix" value="true">
        <os family="unix" />
    </condition>
</target>

<target name="setProps" depends="checkOS">
    <condition property="my.dir" value="${my.dir.win}">
        <not>
            <isset property="isUnix" />
        </not>
    </condition>
    <condition property="my.dir" value="${my.dir.unix}">
        <not>
            <isset property="isWindows" />
        </not>
    </condition>
</target>

<path id="classpath.test">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${my.dir}/project/lib">
        <include name="project.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${my.dir}/project/samples">
        <include name="samples.jar"/>
    </fileset>

    <pathelement path="${build.dir}"/>
</path>

<target name="compile" depends="setProps">
...
</target>
```

The problem is, the ${my.dir} property is not found.  I want to reference either a Linux or Windows folder path within the same ant script, for use on either system.  Looking for guidance as to how to write the relevant portions to achieve my goal?

Comment: Would a relative directory containing libraries be a simpler option? For example a "lib" directory? That would be cross platform. Another option is to use Apache ivy to manage all classpath dependencies. Once understood the later option would externalize all platform specific issues and additionally allow you to leverage Maven repositories like Maven Central